Unable to pull private gcr.io image in Testcontainers.PostgreSql in dotnet 8 test runner, but docker pull works in terminal
When I run my integration test, it fails when trying to start the TestContainer, before it gets to any tests.
Here's my error message:
Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException : Docker API responded with status
code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Head
\"https://gcr.io/v2/my-project/my-image/manifests/latest\":
denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have
permission \"artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts\" on resource
\"projects/my-project/locations/us/repositories/gcr.io\" (or it may not
exist)"}

My test file looks like this:
public class FooTests : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly PostgreSqlContainer _container = new PostgreSqlBuilder()
        .WithImage("gcr.io/my-project/my-image:latest")
        .WithUsername("username")
        .WithPassword("password")
        .WithEnvironment("DOCKER_CONFIG", Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ".docker"))
        .WithImagePullPolicy(_ => true)
        .Build();

    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        // THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION ABOVE
        await _container.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        await _container.StopAsync();
        await _container.DisposeAsync();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void FooTest()
    {
        true.ShouldBeTrue();
    }
}


I've done gcloud auth login
I've done gcloud auth configure-docker gcr.io
I can pull the image no problem from my terminal docker pull gcr.io/my-project/my-image:latest

What am I missing?

As I mentioned in Slack, is docker-credential-gcr (Docker credential helper) available and configured?

Workaround for now:
public class FooTests
{
    ...
    public FooTests()
    {
        PullImage();
    }

    private static void PullImage()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "docker",
            Arguments = "pull gcr.io/bamboo-northstar/snapshot-db:latest",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        };
        using var process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
        process.Start();

        var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
    ...
}

